# Lose certain values from array

Tags: arrays, asp-classic

I've the code to input the values dynamically, when I use it to add the values for the first time, it's fine, but when I want to edit it, the old values didn't inserted on sql query but the new values inserted

Here is the example:
[image]

here is the code:

============the function=================

```
sub ShowItemfgEdit(query,selItemName,defValue,num,cdisable)
        response.write "<select " & cdisable & " num=""" & num & """ id=""itemCombo"" name=""" & selItemName & """ class=""label"" onchange=""varUsage.ChangeSatuanDt(this)"">"
        if NOT query.BOF then
            query.moveFirst
            WHILE NOT query.EOF
                tulis = ""
                if trim(defValue) = trim(query("ckdbarang")) then
                    tulis = "selected"
                end if
                response.write "<option value=""" & trim(query("ckdbarang")) & """" & tulis & ">" & trim(query("ckdbarang")) & " - " & trim(query("vnamabarang"))
                query.moveNext
            WEND
        end if
        response.write "</select>"
    end sub
```

============calling the function================

```
<td class="rb" align="left"><% call ShowItemfgEdit(qGetItemfgGrp,"fitem",qGetUsageDt("ckdfg"),countLine,readonlyfg) %></td>
```

==============post the value======================

```
<input type="hidden" name="fitem" value="">
```

================get the value===================

```
for i = 1 to request.form("hdnOrderNum")
        if request.form("selOrdItem_" & i) <> "" then
            
            'bla...blaa...blaa...
            
            ckdfg = trim(request.form("fitem_" & i)) '<==here is the problem
            
            
            objCommand.commandText = "INSERT INTO IcTrPakaiDt " &_
                                        "(id, id_h, ckdunitkey, cnopakai, dtglpakai, ckdbarang, ckdgudang, nqty1, nqty2, csatuan1, csatuan2, nqtypakai, csatuanpakai, vketerangan, cJnsPakai, ckdprodkey, ckdfg, ncountstart, ncountstop, ncounttotal) " &_
                                        " VALUES " &_
                                        " (" & idDt & ",'" & idHd & "','" & selLoc & "','" & nopakai & "','" & cDate(request.form("hdnUsageDate")) & "','" & trim(ckdbarang) & "','" & trim(ckdgudang) & "'," & nqty1 & "," & nqty2 & ",'" & trim(csatuan1) & "','" & trim(csatuan2) & "'," & nqtypakai & ",'" & csatuanpakai & "','" & trim(keteranganItem) & "','" & trim(cjnspakai) & "','" & ckdprodkey & "','" &ckdfg& "'," & cnt1 & "," & cnt2 & "," & totalcnt & ")"
            set qInsertPakaiDt = objCommand.Execute
            
        end if
    next
```

problem: old value of `ckdfg` didn't inserted to query, but the new value inserted.
How to fix this bug?

Answer (score 2):

You try to post a field with the name `fitem` rather than `fitem_x`.

*Note:* Besides your bug, your code has several bugs including security-related. You don't sanitize the input, for example, for SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: ok I will try, but I use it just to insert new input, and it works fine, but when I want to edit the input, the old input can't capture.
thanks for your advice :) I'll fix the security

Comment: It didn't work..fitem_ used because it's in array the form name.

Comment: It's hard for me to understand your issue exactly, but if I'm right - you won't get your old input submitted. Only the new one. In fact, the only old info you need is the record ID, so you'll know what to update in the DB.

Comment: actually, it's hard for me to explain this, but you're right, I won't get my old input submitted, the odd thing is it's only the fitem that have the problem, all inputs except fitem are fine. 
ok, thanks for your help,